# make ajax parameters secure

Tags: ajax, security

I want to send email value in parameters in ajax. I am using following code it is working properly, but I want to make it secure. no user can check or pass invalid value from calling this action in query string or in any other way. How can I make it secure?

```
$.ajax({
      url: '/Application/UserInfo/',
      type: 'POST',
      data:{email:emailid},
      success: function (result) {
        var json = eval(result);              
       }
});
```

Comment: Secure against what? In transit or by the user parameter tampering?

Comment: secure from user. any can access java script code

Comment: You can't - anything client side can be amended by the user.

Comment: you can add encryption for that purpose @Ashi

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want anyone to be able to see the value of the email parameter, you should consider using HTTPS.

But for passing invalid values, you should do some validation server side where this value is used

Comment: values is email, and anyone can send any email. I can validate only format of email

Comment: before send email we get login from google plus using java script after that if it's successful we send this email to the action, but any one can skip the process of Google-Plus login and can pass email to the action, what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

It may help if you are doing it with two steps at all:

First you can check the email having the right format with a regular expression:

```
/^\w[\w|\.\-\_]+@\w[\w\.\-äöüÄÖÜ]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,18}$/.test(email);
```

Then you may crypt the mail and then you can send it safely.
I am using blowfish. On page loading I generate a key that is set to the javascript of my page. Both, javascript and php have a blowfish controler that can crypt and decrypt any value. I am crypting the value on javascript and send it to the server.
There I decrypt it and check it again with regular expression. The key is not sent to server again, its stored somewhere in the session or so.

To take care that the email is correct you can check whether the domain is reachable through curl or so, but I prefer sending a confirmation mail to the adress and wait for an accept with a generated unique token.

If you just want to get sure of a user signed in with google plus account you may get use of the google plus api and check if the user is logged in. If not you don't accept it.

Comment: user can check encryption method in java and make it's value also encrypt and send from post call

Comment: that is true but cause of this you have to check it on php side and validate it. javascript is always vulnerable...

Comment: You shouldn't encrypt using JavaScript as it is not secure in this instance and also regular expressions are not a good way to validate email addresses.